# How to remove rows with conflicting combination of column values without looping?

Tags: r, dplyr

Hi I have the opposite issue of duplication. Suppose I have a dataframe as such,

```
df = data.frame ( x=c("a","a","b","b","c"), y=c("yes","no", "yes","yes","no"))
> df
  x   y
1 a yes
2 a  no
3 b yes
4 b yes
5 c  no
```

So what I want is to remove `'a'` rows, the reason is because `'a'` has both `'yes'` and `'no'`.  The ideal output would be to retain all rows with `'b'` and `'c'`, `"c"` is retain because it too also has no conflict since it only appear once.

```
  x   y
1 b yes
2 b yes
3 c  no
```

The only way I can think of doing this is to loop through each unique x and test the length of the unique vector from y.  But I'm wondering if there is an easier/ more effecient way of doing this, perhaps  with dplyr?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do a group by 'x' and `filter` based on the number of distinct elements equal to 1

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
     group_by(x) %>% 
     filter(n_distinct(y) == 1) %>%
     ungroup
```

-ouput

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  x     y    
  <chr> <chr>
1 b     yes  
2 b     yes  
3 c     no
```

---

Or may use `subset` with `table` in `base R`

```
subset(df, x %in% names(which(table(unique(df)$x) == 1)))
  x   y
3 b yes
4 b yes
5 c  no
```